# How to track changes to the injected root instance property

Tags: vue.js

I have a property injected like so:

```
Vue.prototype.$authentication = {
 authenticated: false,
 user: ""
};
```

and its working fine.

then in another component I want to track/watch the property changes. How do I do it ?

EDIT

I want to be able to do it like this:

```
 <script>

 export default {
   name: "Login",
   data: function(){
     return {
       isLoggedIn: this.$authentication.authenticated
     }
   },
   watch: {
     isLoggedIn(){  
       console.log('its working');  
     }
   },
 }
 </script>
```

but the thing is, the code wouldn't work.

Comment: That's an anti-pattern. Use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). Dispatch actions, commit mutations and your store will persist across your app, without the need of any watcher.

Comment: but you could at least let me know why it won't work

Comment: Vue only reacts to changes to a particular set of methods which need to be declared upon component mounting. That's why you need to declare reactive properties in `data(){}` as empty, for example. More about reactivity in Vue [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have it solved by looking at the [api](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) doc. So in my component file, I simply do it like so:

```
<script>

export default {
 name: "Login",
 data: function(){
   return {
     isLoggedIn: this.$authentication // remove the attribute
   }
 },
 watch: {
  'isLoggedIn.authenticated': function (){  // now access the attribute
    console.log('its working');  
  }
 },
}
</script>
```

now it is all good.